# WMIC ignores %SystemRoot% during selective process termination

Tags: windows, batch-file, wmi, wmic

WMIC seems to have its own variable for the Windows folder and is completely ignoring the ones listed by my system (using `set`). The command I'm running is `wmic process where "not executablepath like '%%systemroot%%'" delete` to kill all processes running from anywhere but the Windows folder. If I use `%%systemroot%%` or the identical `%%windir%%`, the program runs ahead and kills every running process within its permissions regardless of location. For some reason though, as I've read online, WMIC handles the variable `%%windows%%` and will execute properly with it, but `%%windows%%` is not even a variable listed under my system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a [windows](/questions/tagged/windows) [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file) you need to double the `%` wildcard characters, but not those which enclose your variable name, so you want `%SystemRoot%` but you also want the wildcard, `%%`. As the value of `%SystemRoot%` is always a fully qualified path, you only need to add the wildcard after it. Additionally [wmic](/questions/tagged/wmic) requires that paths use double back slashes, so you'll need to perform a substring replacement, `%SystemRoot:\=\\%`. It is also important to note that there are many processes which tend not to carry an `ExecutablePath` value, so it is wise to filter those out first. Finally, the command you need is `Terminate`, *not `Delete`*.

Putting it all together, I would therefore suggest that you use:

```bat
@"%__AppDir__%wbem\WMIC.exe" Process Where "ExecutablePath Is Not Null And Not ExecutablePath Like '%SystemRoot:\=\\%\\%%'" Call Terminate
```

Comment: Obviously If you want to check what would be terminated before you attempt this solution, you could temporarily replace `Call Terminate` with `Get ExecutablePath & Pause`.

Comment: Thanks for the response. From all I've read, Delete = Call Terminate. Both give "Invalid Query". . I'm not sure what you mean when you say "% wildcard"... is that correct terminology? I'm not following. . I had wmic using %windows% earlier, but in both my regular win7 system and a clean win7 virtual machine it was causing a BSOD when run. Using %%windows%% somehow fixed this and ran just fine. Strangely, %SystemRoot% without doubles in wmic does not BSOD, but it disregards paths and kills all processes. . Using "C:\\Windows" disregards paths. . Can't seem to google what exactly :\=\\ does

Comment: I told you what it was, it's a substring replacement, I'm replacing `\ ` in the expanded variable value with `\\ `. I will mention that the example line I provided above must be run from a [tag:batch-file], not the [tag:command-prompt].

Comment: Additionally, please note that some processes may not terminate for any user.

Comment: I see now. Thanks for your help. This now works perfectly! Lastly, would you mind explaining what the `%%` after `\\ ` mean? `\\%%`

Comment: @jseas, I told you, it's a wildcard. If I showed you this, `C:\Windows\System32\*`, would you know what it meant? In WMIC's Like command it is `C:\\Windows\\System32\\%`, and because you're running it from a [tag:batch-file], the `%` needs doubling, `C:\\Windows\\System32\\%%`.

Comment: Apologies for not upvoting/etc, I typically do that after everything's done but I'll do it differently now. My responses are question-focused but it's not bad to give a "thank you" when it matters. Anyway, I had previously requested clarification on what you meant by `%` being a wildcard and I got nothing on that. So if I understand you correctly, WMIC's version of `*` is `%` within the `Like` command. Looks like I have some WMIC syntax to brush up on... It's definitely pretty weird. Thanks again! :)